# Loading module from directory is different from expectation

Tags: node.js

According to Nodejs load module's rule, if loading a module from a directory, it will parse package.json first and look for "main" field. But it works unexpectation in my machine. It seems to ignore the main field and always loads the index.js file instead.

directory structure:

```
node
--node_modules
--test
  --index.js
  --main.js
--package.json
--load.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js"
  ...
}
```

test/index.js

```
const text = 'test/index.js'
exports.test = text
```

test/main.js

```
const text = 'test/main.js'
exports.test = text
```

load.js

```
const test = require('./test')
console.log(test)
```

When I run `node load.js`, it should output "test/main.js", but the result is "test/index.js"

Comment: Hmm, it works fine here: https://repl.it/repls/IllegalMetallicExtension. Are you sure you didn't mess up something? Any typos, etc?

Comment: Ahh, I can see that your `package.json` is outside of the `test` module. Is that intentional?

Comment: I understand now, i should copy the package.json to test.If test directory doesn't has package.json, always use index.js instead, thanks.@Sebastian Kaczmarek

Answer (score 1):

If you want `node load.js` to output `test/main.js`, `require('./main')` will do that.

If your code were in the root directory of your project, where `package.json` is located, and you did `require('./')`, you would get the result you expect.

That’s because of how node resolves modules.

### Background

There are two different concepts at play here:

1) Node Module Resolution Algorithm
2) The main entry point of a package

#### Node Module Resolution Algorithm

When you do `require('./test')` without a specific file name, node will attempt to load a file called `index.js` as part of its Module Resolution Algorithm. The [steps of the algorithm are described here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) (it’s quite a long list of steps, so I won’t copy it here)

This is completely independent from

#### The main entry point of a package

The `main` entry in `package.json` has a different purpose:

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, **if your package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module’s exports object will be returned**.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main